# @Auth Injection in ContainerFilter

Tags: authentication, jax-rs, servlet-filters, dropwizard, inject

I'm using DW 0.9.1 and it would be cool, if I could inject the @Auth XYzObject into some ContainerRequest or even better in a ContainerResponseFilter (or servlet filter).

Does anyone knows if this is possible?

The usecase: Some users does have different allowd access rates (rate limiting), e.g. max. 2 request per second and max 60 per Minute. This can be verified with the injected @Auth XYzObject.

In the end I can do this also in the Ressource, where this information is available, but as I said it would be cool to do this outside of my ressources in a filter or something else. And I do not want to do this is the authenticating/ authorization process, because rate limiting is not related to this. At the moment,all the variants I tried, nothing works, so it seems not possible, but I hope someone knows the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the `@Auth` annotation works is that it is handled by a `ValueFactoryProvider`, which is used only for (resource) method parameter injection. So you can't inject it into arbitrary locations.

However, when you created `XyzObject` you made it implement [`java.security.Principal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html). The reason DW makes you use this type, is because after it authenticates, it sets the `Principal` in the `SecurityContext`, as seen [in the `AuthFilter`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/AuthFilter.java#L144).

If you look at the implementation for [`AuthValueFactoryProvider`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/AuthValueFactoryProvider.java), you will see that the way it obtains the `Principal` is by [getting it from the `SecurityContext`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/AuthValueFactoryProvider.java#L65). And that's how the `Principal` is injected with `@Auth` as a method argument.

In a `ContainerRequestFilter` (and in may other locations), you have access to the `SecurityContext`. In a filter you can get it with `requestContext.getSecurityContext()`. So in your filter you can get the `Principal` from the `SecurityContext` and just cast it

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    Principal principal = requestContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal();
    if (principal != null) {
        XyzObject xyz = (XyzObject)principal;     
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ahhh this is too simple, looked for a more complex solution. You are right, this is really the best way to do this, perhaps with some more cast checking code. Thank you.

Comment: After some more testing, and looking at the source code, I have a feeling there is a bug. The auth filter is only registered with methods whose parameter has a `@Auth` annotation or the method itself is annotated with one of the Roles authorization annotations (e.g. `@RolesAllowed`). So if you take out the `@Auth` on the parameter, the filter will never execute, unless you have one of the roles annotations.

Comment: Ok, so one way around this is to _not_ use the `AuthDynamicFeature`, and just register the auth filter yourself, and also make sure you _don't_ register the `AuthValueFactoryProvider`. In which case, you can't use the `@Auth` annotation at all. So there's some limitations. Maybe file a bug report if it's a big issue for you.

Comment: Actually scratch my previous comment. I still had the Auth annotation in the filter, trying to inject the XyzObject. That was causing the `AuthValueFactoryProvider` to fail on startup. So you _can_ register the filter and `AuthValueFactory` together. With this combination, the auth filter will filter all requests, and you can still use the `@Auth` in whatever method param you need.